# 'Sitecore.SecurityModel.Cryptography.IHashEncryption' from assembly 'Sitecore.Kernel

Tags: sitecore-api, sitecore-install-framework

I have this problem with the instance of the Sitecore. A made a publish from VS project with the same Sitecore.Kernel.dll and Sitecore.Mvc.Dll of the instance. After that I cann't reach anymore the login page of the site. I have searched over the internet but i didn't find any reference of this problem. Any idea?

**Could not load type 'Sitecore.SecurityModel.Cryptography.IHashEncryption' from assembly 'Sitecore.Kernel, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.**
**Description**: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details**: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Sitecore.SecurityModel.Cryptography.IHashEncryption' from assembly 'Sitecore.Kernel, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

**Source Error**:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

[image]

Comment: Could you make sure that you haven't override the web.config with one from your project?

Comment: Are you sure you've referenced **exactly** the same version of Sitecore Kernel dll as your site uses?

Comment: The web.config in the project was with the action:none, but the web.config in the view was with the action:content. So, I made a publish with the same action before and everything was ok. But when a copy and paste the Sitecore.Kernel.dll and Sitecore.Mvc.dll in my VS Project from my instance and made a publish, this error was appear.

Comment: Yes, the dll are the same

Comment: Which Sitecore version do you use?

Comment: Use a **decompiler to decompile both versions of this dll**, then check if they are really the same. You are most likely to see that you are using different dlls.

Comment: Version Sitecore 9.0

Answer (score 1):

If the type **IHashEncryption** was there before you replace the DLL, that's code for **you are really using two different DLL versions** even if they look the same.

What I like to do in these situations is to use a **decompiler to decompile the DLL** and then make sure the expected type is really there.

You can do this on the new DLL and then on the old one. Most often than not I realize that I was using different DLLs .

I really love **DotPeek** (free), so feel free to take a look [on this link](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/).